# Documentations IPersistedGrantStore interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Обращаюсь за советом. Я начинающий разработчик и ещё не совсем понял, как справляться с такого рода трудностями, может быть сможете подсказать. В моем задании необходимо реализовать интерфейс (**IPersistedGrantStore**). Там есть 5 методов, но что они делают я могу догадываться только из названий(GetAllAsync, GetAsync, RemoveAllAsync, RemoveAsync, StoreAsync). Реализовать, наверное, тоже смогу, но я не совсем понимаю что делает этот интерфейс и документации по нему я не нашел, пытаюсь разобраться сам, но пока что сложно идёт.
Изначально мой подход был таков:

1. найти документацию и разобраться что там происходит (не нашел)
2. попробовать реализовать и под дебагером глянуть что там происходит (тут я остановился на реализации метода **StoreAsync** и не знаю как его реализовать)
3. stackowerflow

Может быть можете подсказать где можно найти какую-то документацию по данному интерфейсу и в целом буду признателен, если поделитесь опытом, как вы решаете подобного рода задачи - когда необходимо реализовать то - непонятно что, так - непонятно как.
Спасибо заранее.
My code:

```
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Stores;
using innRoad.Pms.Identity.Api.Core.Entities.Identity;
using innRoad.Pms.Identity.Api.Core.Static;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ssssss
{
    public class IdentityPersistedGrantStore : IPersistedGrantStore
    {
        private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _dbConnectionFactory;

        public IdentityPersistedGrantStore(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
        {
            _dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<PersistedGrant>> GetAllAsync(PersistedGrantFilter filter) //PersistedGrantEntity
        {
            IEnumerable<PersistedGrantEntity> persistedGrantEntities;

            using (var identityConnection = await _dbConnectionFactory.OpenAsync(DbConnectionNames.Identity))
            {
                persistedGrantEntities = await identityConnection.LoadSelectAsync<PersistedGrantEntity>(x => x.ClientId == filter.ClientId);
            }     

            return MapPersistedEntityToPersisted(persistedGrantEntities);
        }

        public async Task<PersistedGrant> GetAsync(string key)
        {
            IEnumerable<PersistedGrantEntity> persistedGrantEntities;

            using (var identityConnection = await _dbConnectionFactory.OpenAsync(DbConnectionNames.Identity))
            {
                persistedGrantEntities = await identityConnection.LoadSelectAsync<PersistedGrantEntity>(x => x.Id == key);
            }

            return MapPersistedGrant(persistedGrantEntities.FirstOrDefault());
        }

        public async Task RemoveAllAsync(PersistedGrantFilter filter)
        {
            IEnumerable<PersistedGrantEntity> persistedGrantEntities;

            using (var identityConnection = await _dbConnectionFactory.OpenAsync(DbConnectionNames.Identity))
            {
                persistedGrantEntities = await identityConnection.LoadSelectAsync<PersistedGrantEntity>(x => x.ClientId == filter.ClientId);
            }
        }

        public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            IEnumerable<PersistedGrantEntity> persistedGrantEntities;

            using (var identityConnection = await _dbConnectionFactory.OpenAsync(DbConnectionNames.Identity))
            {
                persistedGrantEntities = await identityConnection.LoadSelectAsync<PersistedGrantEntity>(x => x.Id == key);
            }
        }

        public Task StoreAsync(PersistedGrant grant)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private PersistedGrant MapPersistedGrant(PersistedGrantEntity persistedGrantEntity)
        {
            return new PersistedGrant
            {
                Key = persistedGrantEntity.Id,
                ClientId = persistedGrantEntity.ClientId,
                SessionId = persistedGrantEntity.SessionId,
                ConsumedTime = persistedGrantEntity.ConsumedTime,
                CreationTime = persistedGrantEntity.CreationTime,
                Expiration = persistedGrantEntity.Expiration,
                Data = persistedGrantEntity.Data,
                Description = persistedGrantEntity.Description,
                SubjectId = persistedGrantEntity.SubjectId,
                Type = persistedGrantEntity.Type
            };
        }

        private IEnumerable<PersistedGrant> MapPersistedEntityToPersisted(IEnumerable<PersistedGrantEntity> persistedGrantEntities)
        {
            List<PersistedGrant> persistedGrant = new List<PersistedGrant>();

            foreach (var entityPersisted in persistedGrantEntities)
            {
                var persisted = new PersistedGrant
                {
                    Key = entityPersisted.Id,
                    Type = entityPersisted.Type,
                    SubjectId = entityPersisted.SubjectId,
                    SessionId = entityPersisted.SessionId,
                    ClientId = entityPersisted.ClientId,
                    Description = entityPersisted.Description,
                    CreationTime = entityPersisted.CreationTime,
                    Expiration = entityPersisted.Expiration,
                    ConsumedTime = entityPersisted.ConsumedTime,
                    Data = entityPersisted.Data
                };
                persistedGrant.Add(persisted);
            }

            return persistedGrant;
        }
    }
}
```